# How to store images on QTableView (Qt and openCV)

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, qt5

I have a GUI composed of a QTableView with 18 columns and a QGraphicsView where I upload images using a button. I am able to draw a box on a region of interests (ROI) and as soon as I do that with a mouse right click I open up a small dialog. This dialog is composed of a TabWidget with two pages. The first page has a small QGraphicsView that carries the cropped image (say Image A) captured with the previous box drawn. The second page of the TabWidget has also another QGraphicsView that I use to upload a previously saved .jpg image (say Image B) that is on my Desktop. As soon as I hit ok the information on this dialog will be transferred to the first row of the QTableView. Image A will be stoted in one column (column 17 to be precise) and Image B in an additional column too (column 18 to be precise).

I was able to store the cropped Image A (which was the most difficult part because I had to work on understanding the conversion format between Qt and openCV and vice versa) in the QTableView but not Image B (which I handle as simple image that I saved on my Desktop).

I tried different options: **option 1:** I created a function with which I handle the image that I upload on the second page of the TabWidget (Image B), **option 2:** I tried to debug to narrow the problem and it seems that the compiler is not seeing the image I am trying to store.

I am attaching the most important part of the code that are carrying this bug:

In **clipscene.h** is how I declare the most important variables and functions I use:

```
class clipScene : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit clipScene(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~clipScene();
    void setImage(QImage img);
    void setClassifiedImage(QImage img);
    SelectionData getData();
    void setData(SelectionData newdata);

private:
    SelectionData returnData;
    Ui::clipScene *ui;
    QImage simg;
    QImage featureClassified;
};
```

In **clipscene.cpp** this is the function `setClassifiedImage` I use to handle Image B

```
 void clipScene::setClassifiedImage(QImage img)
    {
        featureClassified = img;
        QGraphicsPixmapItem* item = new QGraphicsPixmapItem(QPixmap::fromImage(featureClassified));
        workingImageScene->addItem(item);
    }
```

In **clipscene.cpp** using `setImage` I successfully handle the Qt and openCV conversion of the cropped image

```
void clipScene::setImage(QImage img)
{
    simg = img;
    QGraphicsPixmapItem* item = new QGraphicsPixmapItem(QPixmap::fromImage(simg));
    scene->addItem(item);
    ui->graphicsViewClipped->show();
    cv::Mat input = cv::Mat(simg.height(), simg.width(), CV_16UC3, simg.bits(), simg.bytesPerLine());
    // .....operations...
    // .....operations...
}
```

In **clipscene.cpp** the following `img1` represent the cropped Image A and the `img2` represent Image B (that is currently nor stored neither passsed)

```
void clipScene::on_acceptBtn_clicked()
{
    // .....operations...
    // This will save the cropped Image A successfully
    QPixmap img1;
    img1.convertFromImage(simg);
    QByteArray img1Array;
    QBuffer buffer1(&img1Array);
    buffer1.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    img1.save(&buffer1, "PNG");
    returnData.mSave = img1Array;

    // This will save a different Image B
    // But here the compiler says that no arguments are being passed
    QPixmap img2;
    QByteArray img2Array;
    QBuffer buffer2(&img2Array);
    buffer2.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    img2.save(&buffer2, "PNG");
    returnData.mClassImg = img2Array;
}
```

Finally when all information are passed and stored on the QTableView I am able to DoubleClick on one row of the QTableView and the same dialog I used before for manually storing the data will pop up with all information recorded and both images (Image A and Image B). 
The part of the code that does this on **MainWindow** (and where the bug is connected) is below:

```
void MainWindow::onTableClick(const QModelIndex &index)
{
    int row = index.row();

    SelectionData currentData;
    currentData.mName = index.sibling(row, 1).data().toString();
    // ....additional data....
    // ....additional data...

    currentData.mSave = index.sibling(row, 17).data().toByteArray();
    currentData.mClassImg = index.sibling(row, 18).data().toByteArray();

    QPixmap iconPix;
    if(!iconPix.loadFromData(index.sibling(row, 17).data().toByteArray())) {
    }
    QPixmap iconPix2;
    if(!iconPix2.loadFromData(index.sibling(row, 18).data().toByteArray())) {
    }

    clipScene d(this);
    d.setData(currentData);
    d.setImage(iconPix.toImage());
    d.setClassifiedImage(iconPix2.toImage());

    // ....additional operations....
}
```

I have been struggling with this problem for some days now and anyone who can shed some light on this or provide a solution on how to solve this would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this is still useful to you but since I had the same problem this might be helpful. I think you are never passing the image to the destination table. Are you ever loading the image? Are you ever doing something like this:

**clipscene.h**

```
private:
    QList<QGraphicsPixmapItem*> leftClipPix;
```

**clipscene.cpp**

```
void clipScene::load_classifiedImageFromDb(QImage image)
{
    clasImg = image;
    QGraphicsPixmapItem* item = new QGraphicsPixmapItem(QPixmap::fromImage(image));
    leftClipPix.append(item);
    workingImageScene->addItem(item);
    ui->yourgraphicsView->show();
    ui->yourgraphicsView->setSceneRect(QRectF(0, 0, image.width(), image.height()));
}
```

Also if, as you said, you are trying to upload an image from your Desktop or database, than it may be useful to do something like:

```
void clipScene::load_classifiedImage()
{
    QString dir = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, tr("Open image directory"), "", tr("Images (*.tif *.jpg *.png *.jpeg *.bmp *.gif *.tiff)"));
    QImage image;
    if(QString::compare(dir, QString()) != 0) {
        image = QImage(dir);
        QGraphicsPixmapItem* item = new QGraphicsPixmapItem(QPixmap::fromImage(image));
        leftClipPix.append(item);
        workingImageScene->addItem(item);
    }
    ui->yourgraphicsView->show();
    ui->yourgraphicsView->setSceneRect(QRectF(0, 0, image.width(), image.height()));
    clasImg = image;

}
```

and pass `load_classifiedImage()` function to a `QPushButton`

Comment: thanks for the answer but I already solved the problem. I will mark your answer as correct because I did it in a similar manner you proposed.